# Ruby- How to add comments list to user's dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables: books, comments and users. Tables are related. Users can login and then comment on books. Users have a dashboard. How can I make users see the comments that have been made to their books on their dashboard?
Here are the models,
book.rb:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

  scope :approved, -> {where(status: true)}
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :set_username

  has_many :books 
  has_many :comments 
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  attr_writer :login

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end
  
    # validates_length_of :username,
    #                     :within => 5..50,
    #                     :too_short => " is too short, must be at least 5 characters.",
    #                     :presence => true
  private
  def set_username
    self.username = self.email.split("@").first
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup

  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    if conditions[:username].nil?
      where(conditions).first
    else
      where(username: conditions[:username]).first
    end
  end
  end
end
```

dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = current_user.books
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the book, you can also include the comments to reduce n+1. So in your DashboardController you can modify the statement you have with `@books = current_user.books.includes(:comments)`. This will collect all of the comments for that user's books. Then in the view you can iterate through them like this. Where you can display them however you want, ie, ol/ul with children li for teh comments

```rb
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= book.title %>
    <%= book.author %>
    <p>Comments:</p>
    <% book.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestion for you.
You can write like this

```rb
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = current_user.books.includes(:comments)
  end
end
```

It will get all of the comments you need, especially you also avoid n+1 query.

Or you can also write

```rb
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = current_user.books
    @comments = current_user.comments.where('id = ?', @books.pluck(:id))
  end
end
```